# Functions similar to OnResume and OnPause for a "View" in android?

Tags: android

I have a view that is getting spawned by a service. So there is no `activity` involved with the `View`. So how can I get a callback similar to `onResume` and `onPause` of the activity. There is a method `onAttachedToWindow()` but it is only getting called when the view is attached to the windowManager. If suppose the user navigate away from the view and then reenter the view, it will not attach twice. So the `onAttachedToWindow()` wont get called.

So, how can the `View` know that currently it is entering the screen and when it goes out of the screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can I get a callback similar to onResume and onPause of the activity.

There is no concept of this for "a view that is getting spawned by a service", unless you invent one.

> If suppose the user navigate away from the view

The user has no way to "navigate away from the view", unless you invent one.

> and then reenter the view

The user has no way to "reenter the view", unless you invent one.

> how can the View know that currently it is entering the screen and when it goes out of the screen ?

Since your code is the one that is causing it to be "entering the screen", your code can call something on the `View`. And, since it is your code that makes the `View` go away, your code can call something on the `View`.